Populate Array object using typegoose
I have following structure in typegoose. How do I populate role based on RoleId as it is inside array?
export class PermissionBase {
  @prop()
  permissions?: 
  {   
      roleId?: Ref<Role>;
      role?: Role;

      // Other props
  }[] ;
}

Like I tried as below but without luck. Not getting role populated (of course it won't as we haven't provided how it will be filled)
await PermissionBaseModel()
        .findOne(
          {
            'permissions.roleId': new ObjectId(role.id),
          }
        )
        .populate('permissions.role')
        .exec()


Firstly, typescript (and by extension typegoose) do not support that nested-object syntax, each nested object needs to be its own class with decorators. Aside from that, maybe read into the option refPath or consider just combining those 2 fields seeing as role is likely just a virtual (not stored in the database) and roleId could be populated directly. Maybe also see Reference other Classes (specifically ex. field nestedArray).
